# A specific user can't login (after connecting TV), can't figure out why

Tags: xorg, drivers, users, nvidia, x-server

I have lately installed Debian Jessie on my Dell XPS (1401x, GPU is NVIDIA 425M), installed the NVIDIA driver, and everything worked well.

This evening I connected my laptop to my TV via HDMI (not the first time I have done it) on my general purpose user (not root) and logged out of the user. When I try to log back in, it starts to load the user, shows the NVIDIA screen for half a second, and then jumps back to the login window – no error message, no warning, nothing.

I can still login to all other users just fine, including the root user.

I tried:

- reinstalling `xserver`, `xorg`, `nouveau`
- rerunning `startx` from the root user as my user
- running `startx` through my user after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
- removing `xconf` and creating a new one

... and then I ran out of ideas...

This is the first time I have really used any distribution of Linux.

I've been using Debian for about a month and already installed enough apps so that I don't want to lose this user. 
I would hate to reinstall the whole OS again so I would be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: Try to login again and after it goes back to the login screen, switch to a virtual council (ctrl + alt + F1) then login and run the command "tail -n 20 /var/log/dmesg". Post the output in a code box in your question.

Comment: I think `~/.xsession-errors` will be important too, where `~/` refers to the home directory of the failing user.

Comment: "i would hate to reinstall the whole OS again" — this should be solvable, but the bright side is that, since you have confirmed that other users are working, then in the very worst case the most you should need to do is delete and recreate the problematic user, not reinstall the whole system. You can even preserve the current user's home directory (by moving it elsewhere) and keep using the data after re-creating the user, even moving parts of it back in place after the problem is solved, so long as doing that does not cause the problem to reappear.

Comment: Removing all none default configuration files in the users home directory could be a quick and dirty fix. The problem with this method is that the problem could recreate itself and you would be none the wiser. Although this would narrow the causes.

Comment: @Celada yeah i guess that was a pretty stupid comment :P...

either way, it's solved now, with Jodka's answer, i also isolated the files and checked which was the problem, it turned out to be '.Xauthority'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset the user by moving everything in `/home/faultyuser` to a backup directory like this:

```
mkdir /home/faultyuser/BACKUP
mv /home/faultyuser/* /home/faultyuser/BACKUP
mv /home/faultyuser/.* /home/faultyuser/BACKUP
cp -v /etc/skel/.[a-z]* /home/faultyuser/
chown faultyuser:faultyuser /home/faultyuser/.*
```

and try to login. When this works, move all you need back from ~/BACKUP.

Comment: @user3472411: If this answer solved your problem, you should "accept" it by clicking the check mark on the left — see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).  And once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.